# Is html 5 canvas hardware accelerated on android chrome beta?

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, html5-canvas

I performed some html 5 canvas tests on android browser vs chrome beta. 
Results favor android default browser, although chrome://gpu show that canvas have hardware acceleration.

Test example:
- empty canvas with 8 small images (152 x 128, PNG): 14 fps on android browser vs 13 fps on 
Chrome

Test platform: Samsung Galaxy S II GT-I9100 OS: Android 4.0.3, Chrome beta 0.16.4301.233

Is html 5 canvas hardware accelerated on android chrome beta ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes HTML5 canvas is hardware accelerated in Chrome for Android, but keep in mind that it is in Beta. Please file a bug at http://new.mcrbug.com, and attach your test cases.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on device you are using. Some phones/tablets **are** accelerated, others are **not**. Some Androids also allows users to turn on/off gpu acceleration.

Comment: I use Samsung Galaxy S II GT-I9100 with OS Android 4.0.3. This OS version allow me to Force GPU rendering (Use 2D hardware acceleration in applications), but the FPS in my tests remain unchanged.